# input box taking its own width in bootstrap 3 while including in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I create a table field with bootstrap 3. All thing is going well but when i inserted an input field box in one of td tag its automatically taking its own width.
My code:-

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>Emp No.</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>Department</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
        <td>XYZ</td>
        <td>2323</td>
        <td>Emp Data</td>
        <td>XYZ</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I use css width property to set input field parent i.e td tag. But i don't want to set its width again to make its responsive. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs are full-width on frameworks like Bootstrap and Foundation for a reason: The width is controlled by the grid. This makes coding much easier so you don't have to create exceptions.

If you want exceptions for the table, you could write it something like this:

```
table input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

This keeps the input box responsive while letting you control the width. You can also flip it around and do a min-width but you'll need to create a media query when the screen gets too small.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input tag to take width of its parent container, then you need to add class "form-control" to your input tag.
.form-control gives width if 100% to that form element.